# why declaring a varialble ouside the loop giving different output and declaring inside the loop giving different output?

Tags: javascript, function

I've declared a variable **highScore = 0** inside the function **above the for loop** and I did the when I tried declaring the same variable (highScore = 0) inside the same function **inside for loop**. In both conditions the output is different. Below is my code.

```
/*
i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
     6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
     12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
     19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
     25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
     31, 32, 33, 34, 35]

   */

   var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
          58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
          34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,        
          69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
          46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
          41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

  function printandgetHighScore(scores) {

var highScore = 0;
var output;
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {

 output =  "Bubble solution # " + i + "scores: " + scores[i];

console.log(output);
if(scores[i] > highScore) {

    highScore = scores[i];

    }

}
return highScore;

}            
  var highScore = printandgetHighScore(scores);
  console.log("Bubbles tests: " + scores.length);
   console.log("Highest bubble score: " + highScore);

var bestSolutions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {

if (scores[i]== highScore) {

    bestSolutions.push(i);

}

}

console.log("Solutions with the highest score: " + bestSolutions);



 Output when the **variable highScore = 0; inside function and above for loop**


 Bubble solution # 0scores: 60 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 1scores: 50 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 2scores: 60 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 3scores: 58 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 4scores: 54 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 5scores: 54 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 6scores: 58 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 7scores: 50 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 8scores: 52 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 9scores: 54 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 10scores: 48 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 11scores: 69 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 12scores: 34 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 13scores: 55 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 14scores: 51 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 15scores: 52 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 16scores: 44 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 17scores: 51 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 18scores: 69 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 19scores: 64 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 20scores: 66 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 21scores: 55 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 22scores: 52 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 23scores: 61 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 24scores: 46 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 25scores: 31 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 26scores: 57 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 27scores: 52 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 28scores: 44 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 29scores: 18 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 30scores: 41 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 31scores: 53 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 32scores: 55 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 33scores: 61 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 34scores: 51 bubble.js:29
 Bubble solution # 35scores: 44 bubble.js:29
 Bubbles tests: 36 bubble.js:41
 **Highest bubble score: 69 bubble.js:42
 Solutions with the highest score: 11,18 bubble.js:55**

And only difference when i declare the variable **highScore = 0;** inside the function 
**inside for loop** i get output is 

  **Highest bubble score: 44 bubble.js:42
  Solutions with the highest score: 16,28,35**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `highScore = 0` inside the loop, it gets reset to 0 every iteration of the loop. This means that the next score compared against it (ie. The next array item) will always be higher than it, and will be considered the highest score so far. This continues repeatedly until the final array item, which becomes the last value of `highScore` - resulting in the incorrect conclusion that the final array item (44) is the highest score.

Declaring `highScore` outside of the loop is the correct way to go about this, which results in the true highest score being logged. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CyM7J/1/) implementing your code, and also the incorrect version of it. Note that in `printandgetHighScoreIncorrect()`, the variable is continually redeclared inside of the for loop, resulting in the last array item 44 being the "high score". Try changing the last item of the array, and you should see a direct correlation with the output of that function.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

global variable name `scores` is mismatching with the variable name passed  inside the `printandgetHighScore` function. Try this:

```
function printandgetHighScore(_scores) {
    var highScore = 0;
    var output;
    for (var i = 0; i < _scores.length; i++) {
        output =  "Bubble solution # " + i + "scores: " + _scores[i];
        console.log(output);
        if(_scores[i] > highScore) 
            highScore = _scores[i];
    }
    return highScore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When highScore is declared inside the loop, its value gets reset to zero in each iteration. That is why in the end you see the value of highScore as 44 which is the last element in your array. Keep it declared above the loop to make it work. That way the previous value assigned would be persisted and not reset to 0.